# C program to find area

Tags: c++, c, function, parameters

I am having problems with the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
float area_crcl(int);
float area_rect(int,int);

void main()
 {
 int n,a,b,r;
 float area;
 clrscr();
  printf("\nEnter your choice-\n1.Area of circle\n2.Area of Square\n3.Area of Rectangle\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
   switch(n)
     {
     case 1:printf("\nEnter the radius of circle..\n");
        scanf("%d",&r);
        area=area_crcl(r);
        printf("\nArea of circle is %d\n",area);
        break;

     case 2:printf("\nenter the edge of square\n");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        area=area_rect(a,a);
        printf("\nArea of square is %d\n",area);
        break;

     case 3:printf("\nenter the lenght n breadth of rectangle\n");
        scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
        area=area_rect(a,b);
        printf("\nArea of rectangle is %d\n",area);
        break;

     default:printf("\nU entered wrong choice..\n");
   }
  getch();
 }

 float area_crcl(int r)
   {
    float area;
    area=3.14*r*r;
    return area;
   }

 float area_rect(int a,int b)
   {
    float area;
    area=a*b;
    return area;
   }
```

The output which I am getting is :

Enter your choice-
1.Area of circle
2.Area of Square
3.Area of Rectangle
1

Enter the radius of circle..
2

Area of circle is 0

Why am I getting 0 as output?

Comment: `pi=3.14`... what a wonderful precision

Comment: @Synxis you know, there's **no** `M_PI` in `<math.h>`... Nor is there `<math.h>` at all... >.<

Comment: Also, ***`int`*** `main()`.

Comment: Furthermore, another one to @OP: next time check the documentation of the function you are trying to use - don't make assumptions. That's not any good.

Comment: @H2CO3; I think he is using **Turbo C/C++**, that's why he used `void main()`

Comment: @haccks He could still use `int main()` and `return 0` could not he ?

Comment: @PHIfounder; I used **Turbo C++** and unfortunately `int main`, `return 0` never worked for me!

Comment: @haccks oops !! that was a close call, actually I used it just for few days and before I could understand it better , I just moved on, I think almost everybody starts with turbo C when starting.

Comment: @haccks: I have no sympathy for anyone still using Turbo C(++).  There are far less ancient compilers out there for free...and apparently they're more conforming, too.

Comment: @cHao If you look into some developing countries or some others too the small institutes still start with turbo C , So either the student have to be a born programmer or a family encompassing a legacy of programming to start with something better , so at least in this case they need sympathy.

Comment: @PHIfounder: Or he could, i dunno, google for "free c compiler" and read the very first result...or any of the others on the first page, for that matter.  Nope.  No sympathy.  :P

Comment: @cHao haha , Well obviously :)

Answer (score 7):

Your print statement is:

```
printf("\nArea of circle is %d\n",area);
```

`area` is a `float` and you're using a `%d` format string, which is meant for `int` variables.  That won't work - use `%e`, `%f`, `%g`, or `%a`.

Comment: Dude i have n another doubt now.. why m i gettng value 0 ?? ex if the float value of area is 11.236 in that case %d should print integer part(11.236) i.e. 11 ... why 0 ..??!!

Comment: @DD24, who told you it would print the integer part?  It doesn't work like that.  You *must not* use `%d` to match with anything but an `int`.

Comment: there's an another question .. check this out ..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643161/about-pointers-in-c

Answer (score 4):

For floats, use %f in printf. More generally be very careful to match % in printf's with parameters passed. No check is done and this is entirely at the programmer's charge

```
printf("\nArea of circle is %f\n",area);
```

Comment: Some compilers will actually check the format string (if you use a literal string there) and warn you about mismatched types.  But yeah, don't rely on that.  Always check for yourself.

Comment: Dude i have n another doubt now.. why m i gettng value 0 ??
ex if the float value of area is 11.236
in that case %d should print integer part(11.236) i.e. 11  ...
why 0 ..??!!

Answer (score 2):

You are using `%d` to print `float` that is your problem .

And one more thing other than your error :

Just don't get stuck with `conio.h` , OK ... move on in life :)

Comment: ohh f**k ... this %d ..shitt mann!! 
feeling lyk a dumb .. :/
thnx a lot everybody .. for helpng me with thid stupid question..

Comment: @DD24 And also dump the turbo C as soon as possible, use MinGW or cygwin and try to compile through command interface and if you use linux its even better :)

Comment: Dude i have n another doubt now.. why m i gettng value 0 ?? ex if the float value of area is 11.236 in that case %d should print integer part(11.236) i.e. 11 ... why 0 ..??!!

Comment: @DD24 Look what you see is an undefined behavior which means anything can happen , yes anything ... Actually a `float ` and an `int` are stored differently so there is no conversion going on here, what you see may be any random number. And if I am not wrong ....in standard C the `float` is automatically converted to double so you see the `8 bytes` are used to store `double` and `4 bytes` for `int` , again you are making an exception.

Comment: ahhh thnx a lot ..!! it was quite helpfull..
well thnx buddy .. but i wud like to correct u at a place were u said.. float is automatically coverted to double... this automatic type conversion takes place in JAVA bro.. not in C ..i suppose..m i ryt??? and also here in c int is 2 byte long naa??

Comment: there's an another question .. check this out ..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643161/about-pointers-in-c

Comment: @DD24 I would say , you are not entirely right ,as before `C89` it was automatically promoted to `double` but later on changes were made and this was removed, So either way you don't have to think about that . Now, still there is a difference in how compiler treats them in memory ............. AS for *int is 2 bytes*  ...again I would say that is true for `16-bit machine` ... for `32-bit machine` the `int` size is `4 bytes` .

Comment: For the **if the float value of area is 11.236 in that case %d should print integer part(11.236) i.e. 11**  I .. here you are telling compiler to print an integer while it is float , the truncation which you are assuming, can happen if you do cast that's when you are transforming the value to `int` and decimal digits are truncated, that's it . Now , I would have extended this discussion through chat but your rep is not that much so I will leave it here hoping that I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

`area` is of type `float` and you are using `%d` specifier to print it.
Functions

```
 area_rect()
 area_crcl()
```

both are returning float value which is assigned to `area`(which is also float)
Change

```
 printf("\nArea of circle is %d\n",area);
```

to

```
 printf("\nArea of circle is %f\n",area);
```

Answer (score 0):

printf("\nArea of circle is %d\n",area);

Area is float so above statement will not work, use the correct one below:

printf("\nArea of circle is %f\n",area);